# excel: create an array of averages of two ranges

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need two calculate an average of averages of two excel ranges.
Some values are missing.

for example:
1, 2
2, 2
3, 0
2, NA

The resulting averages are:
1.5
2
1.5
2
and the total average should be 1.75

Is there a way do this in ONE formula, **without any helper cells** ?

---

**edit**  - important notes:
The two ranges are nonadjacent in the actual workbook.
this should run on Excel 2019. no new functions...

Comment: How resulting average is 3 for last one?

Comment: was a typo. I edited it

Comment: Can you give a try to my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty ugly, but it should do the job in this particular case and I think it is suitable with `Excel-2019`:

If only one `#N/A` error is possible per row:

```
=AVERAGE(IFNA(A1:A4,B1:B4),IFNA(B1:B4,A1:A4))
```

If both values can be #N/A per row:

```
=AVERAGE(IFNA(IFNA(A7:A11,B7:B11),""),IFNA(IFNA(B7:B11,A7:A11),""))
```

If it is not actual `#N/A` error, but text:

```
=AVERAGE(IFNA(IF(ISNUMBER(A14:A19),A14:A19,B14:B19),""),IFNA(IF(ISNUMBER(B14:B19),B14:B19,A14:A19),""))
```

Results:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For non-365 versions of Excel:

```
=AVERAGE(SUBTOTAL(1,OFFSET(A1:B1,ROW(A1:B4)-MIN(ROW(A1:B4)),)))
```

If the columns are *non-adjacent* (let's assume `A1:A4` and `C1:C4`):

```
=AVERAGE(
    MMULT(
        CHOOSE(
            {1, 2},
            IF(ISNUMBER(A1:A4), A1:A4, C1:C4),
            IF(ISNUMBER(C1:C4), C1:C4, A1:A4)
        ),
        {1; 1}
    ) / 2
)
```

Note that, if you are not using an English-language version of Excel, the separator within the constants

`{1, 2}`

and

`{1; 1}`

may require amending.

Comment: please note that two two ranges should be non-adjacent.

Comment: @BoTz Added a new version.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a true #N/A, you may need to use Aggregate:

```
=AVERAGE(BYROW(A1:B4,LAMBDA(rw,AGGREGATE(1,6,rw))))
```

[image]

Or maybe

```
=AVERAGE(BYROW(A1:B5,LAMBDA(rw,IFERROR(AGGREGATE(1,6,rw),""))))
```

in the event that you could have two NA's in the same row.

---

A variation on @user11222393's answer for Excel 2019:

```
=AVERAGE(IFERROR((IF(ISNUMBER(A1:A5),A1:A5,0)+IF(ISNUMBER(B1:B5),B1:B5,0))/(ISNUMBER(A1:A5)+ISNUMBER(B1:B5)),""))
```

Comment: Wow. This is really nice.

Comment: Thanks! I thought this would also work in the case of a whole row missing but it doesn't =AGGREGATE(1,6,BYROW(A1:B5,LAMBDA(rw,AGGREGATE(1,6,rw))))

Answer (score 0):

Use `BYROW()` for every row's average. Then use `AVERAGE()` function for final average. Try-

```
=AVERAGE(BYROW(A1:B4,LAMBDA(x,AVERAGE(x))))
```

[image]

For non adjacent columns you may try-

```
=AVERAGE(MAP(A1:A4,D8:D11,LAMBDA(a,b,AVERAGE(a,b))))
```

[image]

Comment: can the two range be specified individually? in my actual workbook, the two ranges are not adjacent

Comment: @BoTz Then use `=AVERAGE(MAP(A1:A4,D8:D11,LAMBDA(a,b,AVERAGE(a,b))))`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try using `MAP()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `D7`

```
=LET(x,MAP(A7:A10,B7:B10,LAMBDA(x,y,AVERAGE(x,y))),VSTACK(x,AVERAGE(x)))
```

---

Comment: does this work with excel 2019?

Comment: No. We assume there is no Excel constraints. Hence all solutions posted works with `MS365` **exclusively**.