# Excel: count non-blank cell pairs

Tags: excel

I have two ranges of cells of equal length (the calls are non-adjacent).
Some values are missing/blank.

I need two count how many of the cell pairs have a numerical value in them.
for example, if the pairs are:
1, 2
2, 2
3, 0
2, -
-, 3
-,-
the count should be 5 (pairs 1-3 have both values, pairs 4-5 have one value, pair 6 has two blanks and is not counted).

Is there a way do this in ONE formula, **without any helper cells** ?
Another constraint is that it should run on Excel 2019 or earlier...

My first thought was to use something like:

```
=COUNTIFS(ISNUMBER(A1:F1),TRUE,ISNUMBER(A3:F3),TRUE)
```

However, this raises an error, and is not even accepted as a valid formula...

Comment: This question is a follow up for this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76278814/excel-create-an-array-of-averages-of-two-ranges

Comment: what is the value of the non-numeric fields?

Comment: it could be either blank or a neutral string (eg "-")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=SUM(IF((ISNUMBER(A1:A8)+ISNUMBER(B1:B8))>0,1,0))
```

Result:

[image]

Keep in mind that date formatted for example as "*dd-mmm*" would give false positive if it is not considered as number in your case.

Answer (score 0):

How about?

```
=INT(COUNT(ValuesRange)/2)+1
```

Comment: I don't think this works properly. The length of cell ranges, and the number of blanks varies. You solution doesn't always return the correct number...

Comment: @Botz, so how have you tried to edit or improve the answer given? What about defining the range as A:A etc

Comment: @BoTz It works if the range only consists of numerical values and empty cells.

Comment: for example, one range has 8 numerical cells, and the other only 2 - The result is 6 instead of 8.